# Galaxy S3 memory leak using createBitmap in very simple code

Tags: bitmap, galaxy

I have been trying to create a bitmap, create a canvas with that bitmap, and then pass it to my onDraw method in an imageView. During this process I noticed that the simple application was leaking memory and so reduced all possible code until I got what's shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createImage(0,720,0,1280);

    }

    private void createImage(int l,int r,int t,int b){

        //Create the bitmap that will be used to draw on
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(r-l,b-t, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
        bmp.recycle();
        bmp = null;

    }
}
```

As can be seen, this code simply creates a bitmap and immediately nullifies it and recycles it.  Despite doing absolutely nothing with the bitmap, it leaks MainActivity on rotation change.

Now, how do I know it's leaking memory and not just a big image? Well, because I got many heap dumps in Eclipse and then looked at the MAT plug-in's histogram, and it kept saying there were always 2 instances of MainActivity around.  This is despite me waiting minutes to ensure that the system destroyed any copied objects from orientation change.

This leak was happening on my T-Mobile Galaxy S3 (android 4.1.1) so I tried the exact same code on my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1" (4.2.2).  Oddly, the app did not leak on the tab.

Here's my question, am I not using createBitmap correctly or is there a big bug in the S3 OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI for anybody who lands here.  After days of testing with a basic, can't be more simplified, guaranteed to have no leak, hello world example, I've concluded that this example too is not leaky.  Instead, this example is simply creating a 1280*720 image with 4 bytes per pixel (~3.7Mb) and the system destroys it on rotation-hence the GC_Concurrent message in logcat.

I know it's not leaky because I've looked at MAT in Eclipse and the only allocated memory, in addition to base app data, is ~3.7Mb, exactly the size of the bitmap. This is true no matter the number of times I rotate the device.

Also, MAT indicated that there were 2-6 MainActivity objects at any given time after first rotating the device.  That's why I thought this was leaking.  But,  there is only 1 image allocated at any given time, so I think MAT is wrong about the number of MainActivity objects when looking at the heap dump.